# How do you reformat a messy code in HTML?

Tags: html, format, prettier, reformat

I'm using a code editor called "Nova" and have "prettier" and "beautify" extensions. At first, I was using just Beautify and it was working well but after I installed Prettier the code got messed up. I can't seem to find an option for reformatting the code.

```
<img
                    alt="거문도호텔 로고"
                    width="190"
                    height="60"
                    data-sticky-width="190"
                    data-sticky-height="60"
                    src="거문도_호텔_로고.png"
                  />
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="header-column justify-content-end">
            <div class="header-row">
              <div
                class="header-nav header-nav-line header-nav-bottom-line"
              >
                <div
                  class="
                    header-nav-main
                    header-nav-main-square
                    header-nav-main-effect-1
                    header-nav-main-sub-effect-1
                  "
                >
                  <nav class="collapse">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="mainNav">
                      <li>
                        <a
                          class="nav-link text-5-5"
                          style="
                            font-family: Poppins !important;
                            font-weight: 500;
                          "
                          href="Index.html"
                        >
                          호텔
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a
                          class="
                            nav-link
                            text-5-5
                            dropdown-item dropdown-toggle
                            active
                          "
                          style="
                            font-family: Poppins !important;
                            font-weight: 500;
                          "
                          href="hotel.html"
                        >
```

The whole document looks like that. How do I fix this? Thank You.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/prettier-beautify/ check this

Comment: Just to clarify, are we talking about [this](https://www.nova.app/) code editor? From a first  look maybe both extensions are conflicting to each other. Unfortunately I cannot install the IDE, could you please share for the next readers more details about settings and extensions list? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it's that code editor 'Nova' by Panic. The only other extensions I use is:
CSS Validator
HTML Validator
TypeScript
Tailwind CSS
JSON

As for my setting, it's default.